# Unable to access custom tableviewcell button properties in Swift

Tags: uitableview, swift, ios6

Working on my first iOS app. I have created nib and a custom tableview cell. The cell has buttons and labels. I am able to access the labels but for some reason I cannot get the properties of the buttons such as set title, for example. I only have access to the following:

```
cell.followUserButton(sender: AnyObject)
```

Why can't I just go

```
cell.followUserButton.setTitle = "Unfollow"
```

I looked online quite a bit. Couldn't find anything. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved my own problem**. I was setting it as only an IBAction. If you want to change the attributes then you **also** have to make the button an outlet too!

`@IBOutlet weak var followUser: UIButton!`

As you may already know, you can do this within the storyboard. Works perfectly now.

Answer (score 1):

You have to write `setTitle()` this way:

```
cell.followUserButton.setTitle("Sample Title", forState: .Normal)
```

Btw `setTitle()` is function not a property.